# Meaning of 'restrict' and 'constrain' in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, difference

what is difference between restrict and constrain in these sentence:

- > In those days women led very **restricted/constrained** lives
- > The cramped living conditions severely **restricted/constrained** the children’s freedom to play.

Comment: Not [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+restricted%2CI+constrained%2Cwas+restricted%2Cwas+constrained%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20restricted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20constrained%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20restricted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20constrained%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20restricted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20constrained%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20restricted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20constrained%3B%2Cc0) showing how signifanctly "restricted" has overtaken "constrained" in the popularity stakes over the past couple of centuries.

Comment: ...so my advice is "When in doubt, use **restricted**". You probably won't go far wrong, since it's logically inconceivable that the ***huge*** usage shift in that chart reflects ***people wishing to convey different meanings today***. On average, we're still saying the same things today that we were 200 years ago - it's just that today we usually use ***restricted*** rather than ***constrained***.

Comment: ...the chart also shows what a massive preference we have for using both verbs in ***passive*** constructions (*I was restricted*, rather than *They restricted me*). Be *especially* careful about using ***constrained*** in "active" contexts, because it's often far less idiomatic (*I **constrained** myself to two glasses of wine* is seriously non-idiomatic).

Answer (score 1):

[Learner's dictionary](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/constrain-and-restrain) says that they overlap between ***constrain*** and ***restrict***. The differences are often overlooked:

> Both can be used in the senses of *holding something back by force* or
> *of limiting or restricting one's actions*.
>
> ***Restrain*** is used more in the sense of ***preventing an action***:
>
> - Congress must *restrain* spending next year.
> - The man turned violent and it took four officers to *restrain* him.
> - I wanted more dessert, but I *restrained myself.*
>
> ***Constrain*** is used more in the sense of ***placing limits, restrictions,
> or controls on an action***:
>
> - The beauty of our sport is that there are hardly any rules to
>   *constrain* you.
> - Industry regulations must not *constrain* innovation.
> - The police hope to impose order and *constrain* violence.

BUT

> ***In actual usage, this distinction may not be very significant to the
> overall meaning of the context in which the words appear.***

So it depends what you want to convey. However, [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=restricted%20lives%2Cconstrained%20lives%2C%20restricted%20freedom%2C%20constrained%20freedom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crestricted%20lives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconstrained%20lives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crestricted%20freedom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconstrained%20freedom%3B%2Cc0) shows that ***restricted*** is more used than ***constrained*** with the nouns *lives* and *freedom*.

As I do not have access to OED, I will quote this [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92696/constraint-vs-restriction) post:

> According to the Oxford dictionary: Restriction, constraint,
> restraint, or limitation? These are all things that limit what you can
> do. A restriction is a rule or law that is made by someone in
> authority. A constraint is something that exists rather than something
> that is made, although it may exist as a result of someone's decision.
> A restraint is also something that exists: it can exist outside
> yourself, as the result of someone else's decision; but it can also
> exist inside you, as a fear of what other people may think or as your
> own feeling about what is acceptable:moral/social/cultural restraints.
> A limitation is more general and can be a rule that someone makes or a
> fact or condition that exists.

Comment: Often, we restrict something from doing something, and we constrain something to do something.